# How to configure Step Load Test in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

We are planning to do a step load test to find the max user our sever can withstand. Scenario is to ramp up 200 user and add steady state of 15 minutes than ramp up 100 user and add 15 minutes steady state. Continue adding 100 user with 15 minutes steady state until the app server cpu reaches 100%.

In performance center we are able to do it, but not sure how to achieve this in jmeter. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use one of the [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups), for example [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) which gives you full flexibility in terms of ramping up, down, holding the load, etc.

For example here is the pattern which matches your requirement for the ramp-up phase:

[image]

You can install Ultimate Thread Group using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

[image]